# Extjs Get Id from database and pass it to component

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Problem I am facing is. I have a form that query the database and get information on cars, I would like to get the Unique Id of that data and pass it to an already made component.

```
 layout : 'fit',
 items : [{
       xtype: 'cargrid',
       autoScroll: true
       //here I want the ID to be passed to this cone
 }]
```

Comment: So basically you need the store containing the data? Can you explain a bit better? Tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, did u want to show the id of the row on the grid ?

1. You need to get it on the store/model. Define one 'id' field on the data store.

**MODEL:**

```
fields: [
             {name: 'idRow'},
             {...}
]
```

1. On the grid, define one column, with same name of "store field id" on the dataIndex:

**GRID VIEW:**

```
columns: [{
        header: "Identificator",
        dataIndex: 'idRow'
    },
        {...} 
]
```

---

EDIT:

If you want overwrite de ID:

See the link belong: [itemID](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId)

and in the comment: (copy&paste)

**Example:**

```
var c = new Ext.panel.Panel({ //
    height: 300,
    renderTo: document.body,
    layout: 'auto',
    items: [
        {
            itemId: 'p1',
            title: 'Panel 1',
            height: 150
        },
        {
            itemId: 'p2',
            title: 'Panel 2',
            height: 150
        }
    ]
})
p1 = c.getComponent('p1'); // not the same as Ext.getCmp()
p2 = p1.ownerCt.getComponent('p2'); // reference via a sibling
```

**Comment:**

```
    Ext.apply(c, {
        itemId : 'p3'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't able to change the component Id, once it get rendered. You can assign before component creation not after creation.

Workaround:

1. Just delete the component and recreate with your new ID.
2. Dynamically create a component and add the require parent component.

As per my understand, `its not possible to change component ID after rendering of component`.

Thanks